# How to briefly change the background color on touch in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

In mobile apps, it is critical to show some sort of indication that the user has touched a specific element, especially when trying to touch an element that will redirect. Hence, I was hoping to change the background colour of `touchableOpacity` element on touch, and then return back to the original background colour.

For example, if the user touches this element:

[image]

The background colour is changed on touch.

How do I do this in `touchableOpacity`?

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  style={[styles.verticalCenter, styles.floatRight]} 
  activeOpacity={1.0} 
  underlayColor="rgba(253,138,94,0)" 
  onPress={()=> this.openModal()} 
>
  <Ionicons name="log-out" size={16} color="#bccad0" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

---

```
floatRight: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderRadius: 100 / 2,
},
```

The above just doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [TouchableHighlight](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight) instead of TouchableOpacity

```
<TouchableHighlight
    activeOpacity={0.6}
    underlayColor="#DDDDDD"
    onPress={() => alert('Pressed!')}>
    <MyComponent />
</TouchableHighlight>;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set `activeOpacity={0.2}` it will make the background lighter. As you are setting opacity to 1 it doesn't change on click.

Comment: The issue is, even though your suggestion works, it creates another problem which I tried to avoid previously. In that, the background lighter is not really a circle, it just becomes a square. But if I were to assign the lighter to the icon itself, then it could fix the issue.

Comment: How to change color? not opacity